# Сортировка имён USB устройств в Linux

Tags: linux, debian, usb

Есть проблема с правильной выдачей имен устройств в линуксе ttyACM[X]. В наличии странная штука под название Симбанк, по сути это хаб модемов, подключаемых к компьютеру через USB. Устройства при каждой следующей загрузке хаотично перемешиваются, и их порядок не соответствует слотам на самом устройстве.

Необходимо, чтобы независимо от места подключения (юсб порт) устройство получало свое уникальное имя.

Пример: Вот так определил в этот раз их линукс.

```
[   12.663250] cdc_acm 1-3.4.1:1.0: ttyACM4: USB ACM device
[   12.663481] cdc_acm 1-3.4.1:1.2: ttyACM5: USB ACM device
[   12.663721] cdc_acm 1-3.4.1:1.4: ttyACM6: USB ACM device
[   12.663972] cdc_acm 1-3.4.1:1.6: ttyACM7: USB ACM device
[   12.665871] cdc_acm 1-3.4.2:1.0: ttyACM12: USB ACM device
[   12.666100] cdc_acm 1-3.4.2:1.2: ttyACM13: USB ACM device
[   12.666349] cdc_acm 1-3.4.2:1.4: ttyACM14: USB ACM device
[   12.666597] cdc_acm 1-3.4.2:1.6: ttyACM15: USB ACM device
[   12.670888] cdc_acm 1-3.4.3:1.0: ttyACM32: USB ACM device
[   12.671109] cdc_acm 1-3.4.3:1.2: ttyACM33: USB ACM device
[   12.671354] cdc_acm 1-3.4.3:1.4: ttyACM34: USB ACM device
[   12.671601] cdc_acm 1-3.4.3:1.6: ttyACM35: USB ACM device
[   12.679536] cdc_acm 1-3.4.4:1.0: ttyACM60: USB ACM device
[   12.679752] cdc_acm 1-3.4.4:1.2: ttyACM61: USB ACM device
[   12.680952] cdc_acm 1-3.4.4:1.4: ttyACM62: USB ACM device
[   12.681276] cdc_acm 1-3.4.4:1.6: ttyACM63: USB ACM device
```

Вот так хотелось бы, причем в любом юсб хабе в любом порту

```
1-3.4.1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
1-3.4.1:1.2: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
1-3.4.1:1.4: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
1-3.4.1:1.6: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
1-3.4.2:1.0: ttyACM4: USB ACM device
1-3.4.2:1.2: ttyACM5: USB ACM device
1-3.4.2:1.4: ttyACM6: USB ACM device
1-3.4.2:1.6: ttyACM7: USB ACM device
1-3.4.3:1.0: ttyACM8: USB ACM device
1-3.4.3:1.2: ttyACM9: USB ACM device
1-3.4.3:1.4: ttyACM10: USB ACM device
1-3.4.3:1.6: ttyACM11: USB ACM device
1-3.4.4:1.0: ttyACM12: USB ACM device
1-3.4.4:1.2: ttyACM13: USB ACM device
1-3.4.4:1.4: ttyACM14: USB ACM device
1-3.4.4:1.6: ttyACM15: USB ACM device
```

По данным из первой таблицы ясно, что нумерация после ttyACM даётся относительно сортировки в первом столбце цифр. Как сделать, чтобы нумерация давалась исходя из сортировки во втором?

Уже понятно что копать надо в сторону udev, но как создать универсальное правило?

Comment: Устройства отличаются по какому критерию? Ну, IMEI, например, у них  у всех разный?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

в приведённой вами выдаче программы *dmesg* нумерация последовательна, а не хаотична.

---

если вам нужна нумерация с нуля и без пропусков, то можете, например, сохранить имена устройств в массив:

```
$ dev=( $(dmesg | sed -n 's/.*\(ttyACM[0-9]\+\): USB ACM device.*/\1/p') )
```

и обращаться к элементам массива:

```
$ echo ${dev[0]}
ttyACM4
$ echo ${dev[1]}
ttyACM5
```

---

а «несоответствие слотам», насколько я понимаю, будет всегда — такова специфика usb-протокола: устройства-то подключаются к одной физической шине (по крайней мере в пределах одного контроллера). кто раньше «отметился», тот и получил меньший номер.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно задачу лучше решить на уровне приложения, идентифицируя модем по IMEI. Тогда не будет важен тип подключения (USB/COM), а также появится возможность определять подключение "левого" модема. Плюс кроссплатформенность (если она нужна).

Answer (score -1):

Есть еще вариант. Дело в том, что Линукс имеет подсистему под названием `udev`, которая и отвечает за именование устройств. Я лично сталкивался с ситуацией, когда сетевые карты `eth0` и `eth1` менялись местами при перезагрузке случайным образом. Решение [такое](http://fx-files.ru/archives/67).
Аналогичным образом, уверен, можно задать имена и для COM-портов. См. [также](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77476/point-usb-phone-to-specific-dev-ttyacm-using-udev) и [еще](http://hintshop.ludvig.co.nz/show/persistent-names-usb-serial-devices/)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.